# OpenLDAP: Error when connecting to Active Directory

Tags: ssl, openldap

I have a problem getting my OpenLDAP correctely running.

I want both the connection from my Application to the OpenLDAP Meta-Directory and the connections from the OpenLDAP to the actual active directories encrypted.

The connection from my Application to OpenLDAP works fine.

But when the assigned User for the connection to the AD tries to search in the AD he gets a cert error:

```
TLS certificate verification: Error, unable to get local issuer certificate
TLS: can't connect: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate).
```

Here is my slapd.conf file:

```
# MDB Backend configuration file
# See slapd.conf(5) for details on configuration options.
# This file should NOT be world readable.
ucdata-path ./ucdata
include     ./schema/core.schema
include     ./schema/cosine.schema
include     ./schema/nis.schema
include     ./schema/inetorgperson.schema
#include        ./schema/openldap.schema
#include        ./schema/dyngroup.schema


pidfile     ./run/slapd.pid
argsfile    ./run/slapd.args

loglevel 32768 16384 8192 4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1
#loglevel 256

sizelimit unlimited
timelimit unlimited


# Enable TLS if port is defined for ldaps
#TLSCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:-SSLv2:+SSLv3:RSA
TLSCipherSuite ALL
TLSCertificateFile C:/cert.crt
TLSCertificateKeyFile C:/certKey.pem
TLSCACertificateFile C:/certCA.cer
TLSVerifyClient try



#######################################################################
# mdb database definitions
#######################################################################


database meta
suffix "dc=example,dc=com"
rootdn      "cn=ldap-openLDAP,ou=Users,ou=example,dc=example,dc=com"
# Cleartext passwords, especially for the rootdn, should
# be avoid.  See slappasswd(8) and slapd.conf(5) for details.
# Use of strong authentication encouraged.
#rootpw    {SHA256}276396e1b1727dbb27f226ad31ed186c8baaf2ddfc3fc7c4120c5ff15524533b
rootpw  ]8+yI7t$#>tg23ET0V:Zry)m.p/@Cl]K^MFIw.0*

uri     "ldaps://firstAD.example.com:636/DC=example,DC=com"
idassert-bind bindmethod=simple binddn=CN=ldap-openLDAP,OU=Services,OU=example,DC=example,DC=com credentials=abcd mode=self
idassert-authzFrom "dn.regex:.*"

uri     "ldaps://secondAD.example2.com:636/DC=example2,DC=com"
idassert-bind bindmethod=simple binddn=CN=ldap_user,OU=LDAP,OU=Service_User,DC=example2,DC=com credentials=abcd mode=self
idassert-authzFrom "dn.regex:.*"
```

When I use ldap and Port 389 instead of ldaps and port 636 it works fine.

Any idea how I can get it working that the two users who should authenticate against the AD servers can do it via ldaps?

Important information: OpenLDAP is installed on a Windows Server.